# Formatting a number with decimal places

Tags: excel

I am trying to format a price that looks like this "193.250". I want to format it to "1.93250".

I've tried playing around with the format cells, but i can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Custom format: `0.00000,,%%`

Comment: @tigeravatar  That sort of works. I'm getting 1.93250%% as a result.

Comment: @Geoffrey - remove the `%%`?

Comment: @BruceWayne results are 0.00019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a custom format that will do that, but you could put this formula in a separate column

`=A1/(10^(SEARCH(".",A1,1) - 2))`

Of course, that will make 100.5 look like it has a greater value than 1000.5. The other option would just be to add a formula to divide by 100 and use the "Increase/Decrease Decimal" buttons to show the desired number of digits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was using /100 to solve the problem, but i wanted to see if there was a way to format it instead of using math.